# Cypress randomly failed with "Http failure response"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

When we create an entity, some request verifies is this entity exists and return 404 it isn't. It works on all envs except China. This request is failed sometimes on this env (but sometimes works well).

For which reason this error could appear randomly?

[image]

From my test I sent the body with string which should be checked to existing on the back-end side.

---

UPD:

My test should check if the domain duplicates or not *(send api call to the back-end and got 404 if a domain does not exist in data storage - positive case)*, but for China environment my test case stops with status 0 error *(on the screenshot above)*.

Code sample:

```
createNewOrganizationWithParameters(domain, address, subscription) {
    this.clickOnTheCreateBtn()
    this.fillOrgProfileTab(domain, address) // here I should recieve 404, but recieve 0
    this.clickOntheContinueBtn()
    cy.contains(this.addOrgModal_subscription, subscription).click()
    cy.get(this.addOrgModal_submitButton).should('be.enabled').click({ timeout: 10000 }) // here button still disabled because of 0 status
}

fillOrgProfileTab(domain, address) {
    this.enterOrgDomain(domain)
    this.typeField(this.addOrgModal_displayNameField, domain)
    this.typeField(this.addOrgModal_addressField, address)
}

enterOrgDomain(domain) {
    this.typeField(this.addOrgModal_orgDomainField, domain)
}

typeField(selector, text, chainer = 'be.visible') {
    cy.get(selector).should(chainer).type(text)
}
```

Execution in spec:

```
createNewOrganizationWithParameters('test', 'test', 'test')
```

I suppose that it happens because of VPN, but not sure, because of when I'm going through the flow manually all works fine *(at least I haven't faced with this issue*)

Comment: Please add your code that you tried.

Comment: @AlapanDas added more information and code